# What is this tool. Pizza cutter?

Tags: tools, antique

It's pot metal, three screws holding it together. It has a sharp rolling disk inside. Looks like it can be held in the palm of your hand to cut something. Maybe leather, carpet, or Pizza. It's at a thrift shop in Frasier, CO.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's an antique wallpaper cutter:

[image]

Yours looks a little rusty, missing some parts, and it looks like you’ve had a replacement wheel that's a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Looks eastern like India or Pakistan. Probably a decorative bread cutter, like for naan or pita type bread. It would be very unusual to see a craftsman's daily use tool (like for leather or carpet) with such ornate casting.